# How can I export or save a inspected object structure in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, object, inspection

Is there a way to save/export (also need to be able to view later) an inspected object structure?

[image: sample inspection window in eclipse]

Possibly export to a XML or JSON structure?

Comment: have you looked into the Serializable class?

Comment: If you just need to view the object, you can highlight it in the tree-structure part of the window above, copy and paste it as plain-text somewhere else. You have to remember to expand all parts of the tree you need though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), e.g.

Java objects:

```
 public class Person {
      private String firstname;
      private String lastname;
      private PhoneNumber phone;
      private PhoneNumber fax;
      // ... constructors and methods
    }

public class PhoneNumber {
  private int code;
  private String number;
  // ... constructors and methods
}'
```

Simply instantiate the XStream class:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
```

Create an instance of Person and populate its fields:

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
```

Convert it to XML

```
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);'
```

Result

```
<person>
  <firstname>Joe</firstname>
  <lastname>Walnes</lastname>
  <phone>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>1234-456</number>
  </phone>
  <fax>
    <code>123</code>
    <number>9999-999</number>
  </fax>
</person>
```

Comment: Im not looking for a programmatic solution. I want to examine the structure offline, with out writing additional code (since I'll be doing this a lot)

Answer (score 0):

I think tostao reply is correct, just create a helper class with static method that you will call during debugging that will persist the XML to some file on the system .

Then use Eclipse "expressions" view to execute the command. E.g :

```
FileUtils.persistObjToXml(obj,path)
```